# Set state using dynamic key in React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a method that set a state variable using the setState. How can I convert this method using React hooks. Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNz2c.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of State it will become:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({});
```

you can invoke setState like this:

```js
setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s almost the same.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});

// …
setState(() => ({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the arrow function inside the set state vs. Anwar Gul's answer at the top?

Comment: It’s been a year, I don’t remember why I wrote it this way. But this is a valid way to call setState, `setState(previousState => newState)`. This arrow function is called "updater", it accepts `previousState` and can return a `newState` to set after compute.

Comment: @mike this usage is not relevant to your question. But still it’s good to know. A bonus effect is the updater function can help you to avoid "stale closure" problem in react, which is a common foot gun, very hard to debug if you’re not familiar enough with react. Using updater function is a common solution to this problem.